# Selenium - How to determine the value on click (findElement)?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

If I have a header on HTML like these:

```
<li class="nav-item px-1 pt-1">
    <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/ciblog/">Home</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item px-1 pt-1">
    <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/ciblog/Book">Book</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item px-1 pt-1">
    <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/ciblog/TestCreate">Create</a>
</li>
```

and I want to click on "Book", how do it?

Here's what I tried:

```
await driver.findElement(By.css('a.nav-link')).click();
```

and I'm  understand  that  won't work because all of them have `nav-link` class, how do I call the specific value of book? on Selenium IDE you can just input value = Book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate it with XPath:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Book')]")).click();
```

Or with css selector

```
await driver.findElement(By.css("a[href*='Book']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say to go ahead with linkText :

```
await driver.findElement(By.linkText("Book")).click();
```